# Div на передний план

Tags: javascript, css

Есть сверстанная страница, на ней блок

```
<div id="element">
    Some content
</div>
```

Я добавил на страницу еще один слой

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Со следующими свойствами

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Хочу динамически по нажатию на кнопку поднять блок  `#element` над слоем `.overlay` так, чтобы он оказался на переднем плане. Пробую с помощью js менять свойство `z-index` например на **101**, в обозревателе объектов видно, что он изменился, но визуально он все еще внизу, под полупрозрачным слоем.

Вместо `#element` может быть любой другой элемент страницы, исходную разметку менять нельзя.
Как еще кроме z-index можно поднять элемент на передний план?

Comment: Попробуйте добавьте элементу `#element` `position: absolute` или `position: relative` вместе с `z-index: 101`

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxbqmq Осталось только JS прикрутить

Answer (score 2):

Для наглядности добавил еще цвет и размер шрифта. До клика на кнопке элемент выделить мышью невозможно, он находится "под". После клика элемент переходит "над".

**HTML**

```
<div id="element">
  <p>    Some content </p>
</div>
<div class="overlay">


</div>


<div class="under">

<button href="#"onclick="changeElement('element')">Открыть Some Content</a>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.1; 
  background:red; /* просто проверить */
    z-index: 100;
}

#element {position: relative; }

.under {position: relative; z-index:500}
```

**JS**

```
function changeElement(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.color = "red";
  el.style.fontSize = "25px";
  el.style.zIndex = "300";
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxbqmq

Comment: Решение для этого примера работает, но в некоторых других случаях (например, если я пытаюсь поднять над оверлеем элемент главного меню) это не срабатывает

Comment: Не срабатывать может по ряду причин, я ответил на поставленный Вами вопрос, исходя из информации, предоставленной в вопросе. Если будет другая информация, давайте искать другое решение в другом вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

**labris,** не бывает такого, что overlay на странице лежит в одном родителе со всеми элементами страницы, так что твой вариант точно не подходит, если хотя бы один родитель этого элемента имеет z-index меньше чем у оверлея, элемент не поднимется над ним:

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container_inner">
      <div class="block-1"></div>
      <div class="block-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.container,
.container_inner,
.overlay,
.block-1,
.block-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block-1 { background-color: red; }
.block-2 { background-color: green; }
.overlay { background-color: pink; }

.container_inner { z-index: 1; }
.block-1   { z-index: 100; }
.overlay   { z-index: 10; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/30w9frdj/6/

На вскидку тут 2 варианта:

1) Убрать все z-index'ы у родителей, но не думаю, что это реально и ничего не сломает

2) Не кошерный, но ... клонируем элемент, задаем position: absolute и кладем рядом с оверлеем с сохранением позиционирования/размеров

Больше вариантов я не вижу =/

Comment: Так смысл-то в том и состоит, чтобы через JS менять z-index у элемента с position:relative. Мой пример работает, как бы то ни было - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxbqmq

Comment: Ты сделал ровно то же самое, что делал ТС ( + со шрифтом поигрался xDDD ) и у него это не работает: "в обозревателе объектов видно, что он изменился, но визуально он все еще внизу".

Comment: До клика на кнопке элемент невозможно выделить. После клика он выделяется, поскольку уже находится сверху.

Comment: Не ровно то же, я добавил Position:relative.

Comment: а, ну да, тогда твой вариант вакуумный, но все же лучше (возможно) чем у ТСа, меня просто сбило с толку то, что ты решил со шрифтами поиграться -_- Однако мне кажется он ему все равно не подойдет ибо "Вместо #element может быть любой другой элемент страницы", я не верю, что бывают страницы без z-index и одним уровнем вложенности.

Comment: @MedvedevDev а можно подробнее о втором варианте? на какой уровень его положить? копию в принципе сделать можно, как её расположить над оригиналом так, чтобы при ресайзе страницы это все не ломалось? Там разметка адаптивная